# Cannot get Bootstrap columns to lay down properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am having an issue that I just don't understand. I believe I have the divs written right, but it just wants to overlap the two imagePlaceholder divs. The HTML is generated by JS based on the number of pictures to display, etc. The only thing above this is a `<nav>` section to generate the menu you see, and this document is included as an iFrame in another document.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="picturesGrid">
    <div class="col-xs-2" id="imagePlaceholder0">
      <a href="linkgoeshere0">
        <canvas id="galleryImage0"></canvas>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" id="imagePlaceholder1">
      <a href="linkgoeshere1">
        <canvas id="galleryImage1"></canvas>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: div layout problem]

the container div is the white area below the menu. The highlighted rectangle is the imagePlaceholder0, which is indented quite far into the container, another weird thing. But you see how it's behind imagePlaceholder1, instead of beside it. It's a very simple layout so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not totally sure based off the information provided, but try setting sizes on your canvas elements and the like, especially if it's being generated after page load. Bootstrap does not do well with elements that don't have size and then suddenly grow or shrink, set it explicitly.

Comment: can u post the css or better give us a jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry I will post soon just busy today. I did however set the canvas width and height and the contained image as well, and it still appears to overlap

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/go2oL62b/

Comment: I have added three pictures against this truck and it seems to only be rendering the last canvas. If you debug it while running you'll see it is setting correct data to image.src, I'm wondering if there's just one simple step I'm missing that maybe it's overwriting the image on each loop...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue may not be with Bootstrap but with the Javascript code; I have reposted the question. Thanks for taking a look!